# nginx udp load balancer changes backend connection port often

Tags: nginx

I am seeing a specific unexpected behaviour when nginx is used as a udp loadbalancer.

Below is my setup topology

Client <-----> NGINX <------> Backend Server

Nginx Listens on port udp 5246, and proxy the incoming traffic to the backend server. As a part of the communication  the backend server ties the connection with the client machine with the incoming port & IP combination and it expects all the further communication from the client machine through the same port.

But with nginx, I could see that my client machine always sends all the packets with same source port. While proxying the nginx always changes the source port and sends the packet to backend server. Due to this the connection gets between the client and server.

Hence can you please guide me on this.

Config used:

stream {

```
upstream backendCapwapControl {
    server 10.155.2.2:5246;       
}                                 

server {
    listen 5246 reuseport udp;
    proxy_pass backendCapwapControl;
    error_log /etc/nginx/log/controllogfile.log debug;

}
```

Comment: You could try to use [proxy_bind](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html) but it will probably not fit your needs. Are you sure you can't change your backend to behave differently?

Comment: @Seth, I don't think his problem is originated by the backend but from Nginx itself. I think this thread is related to mine [Nginx dropping the first client as soon as the second connects](https://superuser.com/questions/1461405/nginx-dropping-the-first-client-as-soon-as-the-second-connects) and in my case Nginx is the one closing the connection and creating a new one using a different port.

Comment: @Ronaldo, i think this issue seems to be fixed in 1.17.3. May be you try that.

Comment: I tried version 1.17.3 as you said, but still no success. Thank you for the advice, though.